# How put separate ajax call to make one section of the page completely responsive while other is still loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, knockout.js

We have a classified website. I have tried to make a minimal version with following fiddle:[this is how basic website looks](https://jsfiddle.net/fx8kqq8u/2/)

Of course we have many more listings and controls. The problem is all this data- 
 1. json to populate all the dropboxes (in actual we have 10)
 2. json to populate listing data

This two comes from one single api. So page is loaded too slow.

If we bring these two data through different api, lets say-"filters api" to populate combo boxes and "listing api" to populate listings.

Is it possible to bring listings first and bind them completely and make the listing section (buttons, links) completely responsive. While in the background put the 2nd api call- to fetch the data from the filters api.

```
<p>
Below are three filters as combo box which too have large data in each combo box. This is called through api.
</p>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Filter12</option>
  <option value="saab">Filter22</option>
  <option value="opel">Filter23</option>
  <option value="audi">Filter24</option>
</select>

<div>
<li>1st listing: This is demo - acutal listing has many elements and listing data comes through api and binded by knockout</li>
```

Comment: Well, the 'A' in AJAX is for 'asynchronous'. One of the benefits is that you can make many AJAX calls and they will each return and be processed as they are ready, without any of them having to wait on others. Similarly, their related UI elements will each be responsive as the data comes in.

Comment: of course you can, just make the calls separately and when the data arrives, load it. you may want to position the elements to be loaded empty in the page so it looks ready even if it's not and set some sort of standby thing that allow the user to know the page is loading and not frozen...  You should be able to make [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) calls asynchronously and receive separate responses... create a variable for each call `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` and separate `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {...}` response listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to split your current AJAX call into two, it would only make sense to chain them. If you load both at the same time, you don't really know which one would finish first - and I'm guessing that you would like the listings to get back first - what use would be having filters populated if you can't filter any data with them.

A quick example using simple JQuery would be chaining the 2 AJAX calls :

```
var filtersCall = function() {
    return $.get('/some/api');
}

var listingsCall = function() {
    return $.get('get/data/api');
}

var populatePage = function() {
    listingsCall()
        .then(function(data) {
            // populate listings
            // e.g. ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.listings)
            // right now user can see all listings, and you can 
            // begin fetching filter data that you need via filtersCall() 

            return filtersCall()
                .then(function(result) {

                    // populate your filters
                    // e.g. ko.mapping.fromJS(results, {}, self.filters);

                  });
        })
}
```